# Zend- 1048 Column 'member_login' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I tried to set up a sign up logic but suffer a problem said

Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'member_login' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `members` (`member_login`) VALUES (?)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1QXH.jpg)

After struggling for hours, still no ideas which go wrong. Here is my source code.
Anyone can give me some ideas?

My Model.php

```
<?php

class Application_Model_Member
{
    protected $_id;
    protected $_member_login;


    public function __construct(array $options = null)
    {
        if (is_array($options)) {
            $this->setOptions($options);
        }
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $method = 'set' . $name;
        if (('mapper' == $name) || !method_exists($this, $method)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid member property');
        }
        $this->$method($value);
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        $method = 'get' . $name;
        if (('mapper' == $name) || !method_exists($this, $method)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid member property');
        }
        return $this->$method();
    }

    public function setOptions(array $options)
    {
        $methods = get_class_methods($this);
        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            $method = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
            if (in_array($method, $methods)) {
                $this->$method($value);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->_id = (int) $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }

    public function setMemberLogin($text)
    {
        $this->_member_login = (string) $text;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getMemberLogin()
    {
        return $this->_member_login;
    }


}
```

My MemberMapper.php

```
<?php

class Application_Model_MemberMapper
{
    protected $_dbTable;

    public function setDbTable($dbTable)
    {
        if (is_string($dbTable)) {
            $dbTable = new $dbTable();
        }
        if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided');
        }
        $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDbTable()
    {
        if (null === $this->_dbTable) {
            $this->setDbTable('Application_Model_DbTable_Members');
        }
        return $this->_dbTable;
    }

    public function save(Application_Model_Member $member)
    {
     $data = array(
     'member_login' => $member->getMemberLogin(),

        );

        if (null === ($id = $member->getId())) {
            unset($data['member_id']);
            $this->getDbTable()->insert($data);
        } else {
            $this->getDbTable()->update($data, array('member_id = ?' => $id));
        }
    }

    public function find($id, Application_Model_Member $member)
    {
        $result = $this->getDbTable()->find($id);

        if (0 == count($result)) {
            return;
        }
        $row = $result->current();

        $member->setId($row->member_id)
              ->setMemberLogin($row->member_login);


    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll();
        $entries   = array();
        foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
            $entry = new Application_Model_Member();
            $entry->setId($row->member_id)
                  ->setMemberLogin($row->member_login);

            $entries[] = $entry;
        }
        return $entries;
    }
}

DbTable:
class Application_Model_DbTable_Members extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{   
    protected $_name = 'members';    
}
```

Form: Registration.php

```
<?php
class Application_Form_Auth_Registration extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $this->addElement(
            'text', 'member_login', array(
                'label' => 'Username:',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'    => array('StringTrim')
            ));


        $this->addElement('submit', 'register', array(
            'ignore'   => true,
            'label'    => 'Sign up'
            ));
    }
}
```

Signup controller:

```
public function signupAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $regform = new Application_Form_Auth_Registration();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($regform->isValid($request->getPost())) {
            $member = new Application_Model_Member($regform->getValues());
            $mapper = new Application_Model_MemberMapper();
            $mapper->save($member);
            return $this->_helper->redirector('/books/view');
        }
    }

    $this->view->regform = $regform;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fix the bug. It go wrong with the naming of Element. For example, in your database you have "member_login", then the Element name should be sth like memberLogin.